# flatten nested data in R

Tags: r, nested

UPDATED:
I've been searching for related questions here and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I need to flatten some nested data. My data frame currently looks something like this:

```
Col_A | Col B
red   | 1
red   | 2
red   | 4
red   | 5
blue  | 2
blue  | 2
blue  | 3
green | 1
green | 2
green | 3
green | 3
green | 7
green | 9
black | 4
orange| 1
orange| 2
```

However, I would like it to look like this:

```
A     | B | C | D | E | F | G |
red   | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | NA| NA|
blue  | 2 | 2 | 3 | NA| NA| NA|
green | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 7 | 9 |
black | 4 | NA| NA| NA| NA| NA|
orange| 1 | 2 | NA| NA| NA| NA|
```

I tried using `dplyr::group_by()` but apparently I don't understand it correctly as it does nothing to my data frame. Any ideas? I assume there's a very straightforward/simple function that does this for me. If not, I guess I can try to loop it out :(

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`'s built in (efficient) equivalent to `reshape2`'s `dcast`:

```
library(data.table) #1.9.5+, use dcast.data.table in earlier versions
setDT(x)
> dcast(x[, .(Col_B,1:.N), by=Col_A], Col_A~V2, value.var="Col_B")
    Col_A 1  2  3  4  5  6
1: black  4 NA NA NA NA NA
2: blue   2  2  3 NA NA NA
3: green  1  2  3  3  7  9
4: orange 1  2 NA NA NA NA
5: red    1  2  4  5 NA NA
```

If `Col_A` is already stored in your `data.frame` as a factor with the proper level ordering, `dcast` will preserve this order, otherwise we might specify:

```
x$Col_A<-factor(x$Col_A, levels=unique(x$Col_A))
setDT(x)
> dcast(x[, .(Col_B,1:.N), by=Col_A], Col_A~V2, value.var="Col_B")
    Col_A 1  2  3  4  5  6
1: red    1  2  4  5 NA NA
2: blue   2  2  3 NA NA NA
3: green  1  2  3  3  7  9
4: black  4 NA NA NA NA NA
5: orange 1  2 NA NA NA NA
```

If you'd like the names to be as you wrote in your post, use `setnames`:

```
setnames(dcast(x[,.(Col_B,1:.N),by=Col_A],
               Col_A~V2,value.var="Col_B"),
         LETTERS[1:7])[]
        A B  C  D  E  F  G
1: red    1  2  4  5 NA NA
2: blue   2  2  3 NA NA NA
3: green  1  2  3  3  7  9
4: black  4 NA NA NA NA NA
5: orange 1  2 NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `spread` in the tidyr package. If your data looks like:

```
d <- data.frame(Col_A = rep(c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "orange"), c(4, 3, 6, 1, 2)),
                Col_B = c(1:4, 1:3, 1:6, 1, 1:2))
```

Then you can do:

```r
spread(d, Col_B, Col_B)
#>    Col_A 1  2  3  4  5  6
#> 1  black 1 NA NA NA NA NA
#> 2   blue 1  2  3 NA NA NA
#> 3  green 1  2  3  4  5  6
#> 4 orange 1  2 NA NA NA NA
#> 5    red 1  2  3  4 NA NA
```

Note that yours is a slightly odd case for spread since you're using the same values to spread across the columns and to fill the values. It looks like you want the columns to be named based on letters. One approach to this is:

```r
d %>%
    mutate(letter = LETTERS[Col_B + 1]) %>%
    spread(letter, Col_B)
#>    Col_A B  C  D  E  F  G
#> 1  black 1 NA NA NA NA NA
#> 2   blue 1  2  3 NA NA NA
#> 3  green 1  2  3  4  5  6
#> 4 orange 1  2 NA NA NA NA
#> 5    red 1  2  3  4 NA NA
```

The specifics of how you rename the columns, however, depends on your particular data.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect... Also, you were a fantastic basketball player Mr. David Robinson. One of the greatest!

Comment: On second thought, I just realized that I may not have expressed my question carefully enough as this doesn't quite do what I need it to, but it's close. I edited my question to reflect the real problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `reshape2` package.
Add column with future column names and cast the data.frame to a new data.frame.

```
d <- data.frame(Col_A = rep(c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "orange"), c(4, 3, 6, 1, 2)), 
                Col_B = c(1:4, 1:3, 1:6, 1, 1:2))
d$L <- LETTERS[d$Col_B + 1]
reshape2::dcast(d, Col_A ~ L, value.var = "Col_B")

#output
   Col_A B  C  D  E  F  G
1  black 1 NA NA NA NA NA
2   blue 1  2  3 NA NA NA
3  green 1  2  3  4  5  6
4 orange 1  2 NA NA NA NA
5    red 1  2  3  4 NA NA
```

Comment: Why not simply `dcast(d,formula=Col_A~Col_B,value.var="Col_B")` ?